Absolute Convergence of Fourier Series Proof
I am looking at the following theorem

Let $f$ and $g$ be two piecewise continuous, periodic functions with the same period $p$ and with Fourier series
$$\begin{align}
 \mathcal{F}[f]|_{t} = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_{k}e^{i 2\pi \omega_{k}t} \\
 \mathcal{F}[g]|_{t} = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \tilde{c}_{k}e^{i 2\pi \omega_{k}t} \\
\end{align}$$
Assume, in addition, that $g$ is continuous and piecewise smooth, then
$$\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_{k}\tilde{c}^*_{k}$$ converges absolutely

I will summarize my proof as follows

We use Bessel's inequality
$$\begin{align}
 \sum_{k=1}^N \lvert c_{k} \rvert^2 \lvert\lvert \phi_{k} \rvert\rvert^2 \leq \lvert\lvert f \rvert\rvert^2   
\end{align}$$
Note, we are using the the complex exponential Fourier series and therefore extend the range of the $k$ into the negatives.
$$\sum_{k=-N}^N \lvert c_{k} \rvert^2 \lvert\lvert e^{-i 2 \pi \omega_{k}t} \rvert\rvert^2 \leq \lvert\lvert f \rvert\rvert^2   $$
We can compute the norm of the exponential using inner product. For simplicity assume that the period is defined over the interval $[0,p]$
$$\begin{align}
 \lvert\lvert e^{-i 2 \pi \omega_{k}t} \rvert\rvert^2 &= \left\langle e^{-i 2 \pi \omega_{k}t}\,,\,e^{-i 2 \pi \omega_{k}t} \right\rangle  \\
 &= \int_{0}^p e^{-i 2 \pi \omega_{k}t}(e^{-i 2 \pi \omega_{k}t})^* \, dt  \\
 &= \int_{0}^p e^{-i 2 \pi \omega_{k}t}e^{+i 2 \pi \omega_{k}t} \, dt  \\
 &= \int_{0}^p e^{0} \, dt  \\ 
 &= p
\end{align}$$
Therefore, we get
$$\begin{align}
 \sum_{k=-N}^N \lvert c_{k} \rvert^2 \lvert\lvert e^{-i 2 \pi \omega_{k}t} \rvert\rvert^2 \leq \lvert\lvert f \rvert\rvert^2  &\iff p\sum_{k=-N}^N \lvert c_{k} \rvert^2  \leq \lvert\lvert f \rvert\rvert^2  \\
 &\iff \sum_{k=-N}^N \lvert c_{k} \rvert^2  \leq \frac{1}{p}\lvert\lvert f \rvert\rvert^2 
\end{align}$$
We can now make the following assertion for both of the functions
$$\begin{align}
 \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \lvert c_{k} \rvert^2 &\leq \frac{1}{p} \lvert\lvert f \rvert\rvert^2 \tag{1a}\\  
 \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \lvert \tilde{c}_{k} \rvert^2 &\leq \frac{1}{p} \lvert\lvert g \rvert\rvert^2   \tag{1b}
\end{align}$$
We now show the first claim using the previous results and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$\begin{align}
 \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \lvert c_{k}\tilde{c}_{k}^* \rvert &= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \lvert c_{k} \rvert \, \lvert \tilde{c}_{k} \rvert  \tag{Complex Property} \\
 &\leq \left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \lvert c_{k} \rvert^2 \right)^{1/2}  \left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \lvert \tilde{c}_{k} \rvert^2 \right)^{1/2} \tag{Cauchy-Schwarz} \\
 &\leq \lvert\lvert f \rvert\rvert \; \lvert\lvert g \rvert\rvert \tag{Result 1b, 1a Root}  
\end{align}$$

My question is:
Going from the second last line to the last line, using the results from (1a) and (1b), how does the $1/p$ term vanish from the result. If $0 \leq p < 1$ then this inequality shouldn't necessarily hold. Reading the theorem there is no requirement of $1 \leq p < \infty$.
What am I missing? Or did I make incorrect assertions in my proof?

Have not read your proof but, from assumptions, both functions are in $L^2$ hence Fourie's coefficients are in $l^2$. The rest follows from Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. Also, there is a theorem due to Bernstein which asserts that if a function is Holder with exponent $> 1/2$ then its Fourier's coefficients  are in $l^1$.

Thank you for your comment, but I am especially interested in why the 1/p vanishes in the last line of the proof.

$p=1$ in the proof of the Bessel inequality. In words, there is no $p$.

As far as I know there must be a $p$ which can also be different from one, since $p$ describes the length of the interval, which can be found in the result (1a) and (1b).
You are right, that Bessel's inequality in itself does not use $p$, but we take the inner product on the complex exponential term. Since we use the $L^2$ norm and the corresponding inner product, we yield a $p$ which comes from the interval over which we define our functions.
If there is a misconception at my end, I am happy to learn about it.

Well. this is a kind of misunderstanding. In Bessel inequality one deals with orthonormal sequence of functions, that is orthogonal with norm 1.  In this case there is no need for "p". If we do not assume that the functions have norm 1 then the Bessel inequality changes of course and the value of norm of the sequence has to eb taken into account.
